# Flexible width of a button

Tags: css, primefaces, styles

I am using below CSS for my button

```
 .ui-button-text {
background-color:#3e9cbf !important;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #F0F8FF !important;
width: 50px;
}
```

Here if you will check ,i am using `width: 50px;`  but i want the width of button shuold be flexible it should change width according to text size if button text is `Submit` then button width will small but if text is something like this `Post Your Question` now button width should change.
How can we achieve this with css ?

Comment: Did not get you man :)

Comment: Litigation-happy societies, that's the problem! :-)

Comment: @David-SkyMesh problem is button width

Comment: @JavaProgrammer actually you did!

Comment: @JavaProgrammer lets come back to the context, check the answer below..is that what you need ? which is pretty simple to achieve though

Comment: Yeah, just don't set a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a div then you need to set it to `display:inline-block` then you do not need to set a width.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/kw3La/

```
.ui-button-text {
    background-color:#3e9cbf !important;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #F0F8FF !important;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto !important; 
}
```

Comment: You have used `!important` in your example. This would also work for `width: auto;` along with the other styles in this element

Comment: That the issue i have to add  width: auto !important;

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcqPG/)

CSS:

```
.ui-button-text {
background-color:#3e9cbf !important;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #F0F8FF !important;
    padding:2px 6px;
}
```

html:

```
<button class="ui-button-text">Submit</button>
<button class="ui-button-text">Post your question</button>
```

[image]

However if you're talking about overriding the css that is coming from `.ui-button-text`, then do as here : http://jsfiddle.net/bcqPG/1/

CSS:

```
.ui-button-text {
background-color:#3e9cbf !important;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #F0F8FF !important;
    width:50px;
}

button.ui-button-text{
    width:auto;
    padding:2px 6px;
}
```